# I do not receive the push notification Firebase in my iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have the following settings in my AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseFirestore
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import UserNotificationsUI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        //Api Google masps
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyDz1yCQldDsfUAhkV0nRcfxqYknTlD1nlMQWEQe")
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyDz1yCQldDsfUAhkV0nRcfxqYknTlD1nlQWQEDM")

        //Inicio del projecto en firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()



        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        //Decimos cual es la pantalla principal con la que iniciara la aplicacion
        let mainViewController = ContainerController()
        window?.rootViewController = mainViewController

        //Configuracion del inicio de sesion google
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self


        //Configuracion de las push Notificatios
        //Delegate UserNotifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (_, error) in
            guard error == nil else{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }

        //Solicit permission from the user to receive notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (_, error) in
            guard error == nil else{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }

        //get application instance ID
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
            } else if let result = result {
                print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
            }
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }



    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                return
            }
            print("Entro al AUTH")
            guard let email = authResult?.user.email else {return}
            guard let name = authResult?.user.displayName else {return}
            guard let image = authResult?.user.photoURL else {return}
            guard let uid = authResult?.user.uid else {return}
            let profileImageUrl = image.absoluteString

            let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "image": profileImageUrl] as [String : Any]
            let db = Firestore.firestore()

            db.collection("users").document(uid).setData(values){ (err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error al agregar documento: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                }else{
                    print("Se agrego el documento con el ID: \(uid)")
                    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                    //Decimos cual es la pantalla principal con la que iniciara la aplicacion
                    let mainViewController = MainViewController()
                    self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
        return
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "IoTaxiConcesionario")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the push notification enabled in the application

[image]

And in Firebase I have registered my Auth Key
[image]

Running my application runs on the device, and I receive a firebase token.

[image]

But when I run a test message from Firebase I don't receive the notification on the phone or on the console.

Comment: Are you putting the app in the background? Is the Provisioning Profile enabled for Push Notifications?

Comment: Please do NOT include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Si, la aplicación esta en segundo plano e instale el Provisioning Profile

Comment: Code formatting is important to make it readable and length is super important. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) stressing the word minimal

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and just solved it by disabling method swizzling. Here's a link on how to do it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Basically you need to do this:

> Developers who prefer not to use swizzling can disable it by adding the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled in the app’s Info.plist file and setting it to NO (boolean value).

And then:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
             didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
             Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```